# Interface-oriented: Fragmentized interfaces to represent a data structure

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I'm inspired from encapsulation achieved by interfaces. Interface is a powerful tool when objects shares common properties and methods. Interface-oriented designs are designs that decouple entities and the manager that are managing them. They do not need to know any of the implementation  details and the exact type, and a typical good interface design is that object that passed through the method call could be hot-plugged at runtime.

So I managed to turn my objects to expose through interfaces.

Suppose I have a `LoginModule`, which contains the business logic to handle the submitted `Form` by `Client`. For example, the client may either login through enter `Username` and `Password` or with their `MobileNo`

```
public class UserLoginForm
{
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
public class MobileLoginForm
{
  public string MobileNo { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then the business logic layer is going to take a look at the request.

```
public class LoginModule
{
  public int LoginByUsername(UserLoginForm form)
  {
    // DoSomething, such as CheckDbIfExist(form.Username);
    // return the result, e.g. -1 stand for wrong password
  }
   public int LoginByMobileNo(MobileLoginForm form)
  {
    // DoSomething, such as CheckDbIfExist(form.Username);
    // return the result, e.g. -1 stand for wrong password
  }
}
```

In this example, the two logics are so similar that `LoginByMobileNo` could eventually direct to call `LoginByUserName` after getting the `Username` by looking up `MobileNo` in the database.

But you know, it just couldn't because we need a `UserLoginForm` to call it, or we just create a separated method `Login(string username, string password)` to let both login method to call it.

The actual consideration is not on how to reconstruct these two methods, as there are many other types of request, something like `CokeRequest` that request a coke delivery to `int RoomNo` and `int Count`... ...

```
public interface ILoginModule
{
   void LoginByUsername(XXX xxx);
}
```

**First Question: What is that `XXX`?**

This interface have no access to `UserLoginForm`, he don't know the existance of that form anyway. If I am doing the interface design correctly, `XXX` should be an interface that he could know its existance.

```
public interface ILoginModule
{
   void LoginByUsername(IUserLogin login);
   void LoginByMobile(IMobileLogin login);
}
// LoginModule now implement ILoginModule

public interface IUserLogin
{
   string UserName { get; set; }
   string Password { get; set; }
}
public interface IMobileLogin
{
   string MobileNo { get; set; }
   string Password { get; set; }
}
// The the two Forms now implement the respective interface
```

**By then the nightmare begun. I find to needing a dedicated interface for every Request that the client made**

> An interesting observation:
>
> Service interfaces are Method-only interfaces
>
> Request interfaces are Property-only interfaces

I do not believe it is the right way to do deal with interfaces.

Neither if we fragmentize the interfaces.

```
public interface ILoginModule
{
   void LoginByUsername(IUserLogin login);
   void LoginByMobile(IMobileLogin login);
}
// LoginModule now implement ILoginModule

public interface IPassword
{
   string Password { get; set; }
}
public interface IUserLogin : IPassword
{
   string UserName { get; set; }
}
public interface IMobileLogin : IPassword
{
   string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
// The the two Forms now implement the respective interface
```

Because we are still needing hundreds of interface (which is of same variety as the requests to be)
**Nor**

```
public interface ILoginModule
{
   void LoginByUsername(IUser login1, IPassword login2);
   void LoginByMobile(IMobile login, IPassword login2);
}
// LoginModule now implement ILoginModule

public interface IPassword
{
   string Password { get; set; }
}
public interface IUser
{
   string UserName { get; set; }
}
public interface IMobile
{
   string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
// The the two Forms now implement the respective interface
```

It smells bad because we are no different from passing the string content one by one. If the request contains 8 param, then the method becomes `DoWork(form,form,form,form,form,form,form,form)`

I really can't figure out why I'm falling into this irony. If I have n types of requests, it is normal to give them to m modules to handle, it still n methods in total. If we use interface, it adds n interfaces to represent n request, and this didn't help to hot-plug data at anytime because *each interface get only one single implementation*.

In this situation the LoginModule can't even benefit from it: It could not call `LoginByUsername` after finding out the `Username` which corresponds to `MobileNo` at any circumstances...

Most interface tutorial is taking about `car` and `bus` and `racecar` in which they `void StartEngine()`...While seldom for architecture, or communication between layers, just for instance, the MVC model.

I'm not saying interfaces are bad, but I need a way to correctly implement it or should I implement it in this situation. Any misused patterns are antipattern with no single doubt.
I hope to hear any voices.

Answer (score -1):

After hours of consideration, it was found the starting point was problematic, leading to problematic solutions.

The answer of using interfaces to represent a data structure is **nope**. It is useless to declare property-only interfaces.

The request submitted by the client is anemic when it comes to the business logic just take its properties and do the work.

That says, `ILoginModule` that defines `void LoginWithMobile(string MobileNo, string Password)` is already enough for handling the request without passing the `Request` itself as a parameter.

> An interface is useful for abstraction of "what it does" instead of
>   "what it contains". Therefore all objects that aims to store data
>   without itself managing them should not implement any interface.